# Using PHP to display a div only if on a certain page

Tags: php, html

What I would like to do is add a div to the header of my document only if the header is displayed on a certain page, here is what I imagined it might be:

```
 <?php if (is_front_page()) {<div class="spotlight"></div>} ?>
```

That snippet results in a fatal error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected`

Is it possible to use PHP to add a div only on a certain page using PHP, I believe this may be accomplished with JavaScript, but would prefer to use PHP.

Comment: You can't just switch from PHP to HTML.  It confuses the parser, as you can see.  See Mathieu below for several ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction:

```
 <?php if (is_front_page()) {?> <div class="spotlight"></div><? } ?>
```

Or:

```
 <?php if (is_front_page()) {echo '<div class="spotlight"></div>'} ?>
```

Or:

```
 <?php if (is_front_page()) {echo "<div class=\"spotlight\"></div>"} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) print '{<div class="spotlight"></div>}'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`<?php if (is_front_page()) {?><div class="spotlight"></div><?php } ?>`

OR

`<?php if (is_front_page()) { echo "<div class='spotlight'></div>";} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes and semi-colon.

Try this

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { echo '<div class="spotlight"></div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: He's also missing the echo - kind of important. :)